# Where to store reusable data in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

here is my use case.

My dara are currency rates ( i.e. date, currency, rate...ex 2021/03/05,USD,23.05 ) i received that each day for many  currency.

There are first going to a topic called rates_topic, stored with a key of format date-currency.

So far i am ok. Next step I need to store some aggregated values from rates_topic , i.e. i need to store the last rate of the month by currency  and the average rate per currency per month.

Theses aggregated values should be reused/consumed by others different kafka-streams.

Where woukd you store thoses aggregated values? States stores? Globalktable? Ksqldb ?

NOTE : I am in a mutiple brokers, multiple partitions, multiple instances environment.

Thanks for any comment/pointers

Comment: Sounds like you need a compacted topic to keep the latest value for a given key. Not familiar with Kafka Streams API but this would be the true Kafka way to do it.

Comment: All the options you listed are basically the same thing. Ksql creates KTables using Kafka Streams API, which use state stores to aggregate values

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah... they all end up in a kind of store. but still which one would be the more appropriate. heard that statestore are instance-localized if used directly... dont know too much about globalktable nor ksqldb

Comment: GlobalKTable sounds like what you want, but you can join streams against regular KTables, too. StateStores can be replicated and distributed. If you're uncomfortable with JVM programming, then you can use KSQL